# Connection between some inequalities

Tags: inequality

Let $I \subset \mathbb{R}$ be an interval, $f: I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function and let $n \geq 2, n \in \mathbb{N}$ be fixed number.

Let's consider the following conditions:

1. $\displaystyle f\left(\frac{x_1+x_2}{2}\right) \leq \frac{f(x_1)+f(x_2)}{2}  \textrm{ for } x_1, x_2 \in I$;
2. $\displaystyle f\left(\frac{x_1+...+x_n}{n}\right) \leq \frac{f(x_1)+...+f(x_n)}{n}
   \textrm{ for } x_1,...,x_n \in I$.

By https://math.stackexchange.com/a/83398/22907 1. implies 2.

Does 2. imply 1. ?

Comment: isn't (2) a special case of (1), when you set n to 2?

Comment: If $n$ is even, $n=2p$ just take $x_1=\ldots=x_p=a$ and $x_{p+1}=\ldots,=x_{2p}=b$. If $n=2p+1$, put $x_1=\ldots=x_p=a$, $x_{p+1}=\ldots=x_{2p}=b$ and $x_{2p+1}=\frac{a+b}2$.

Comment: @Emmad: That's what I thought when I looked at the question at the first sight. But I looked at it again, I found that here $n$ is fixed.

Comment: Offtop: Is the implication (2 to 1) also true if we demand $x_i \lt x_{i+1}$ and do not assume continousity / measurability of $f$?

Comment: @Davide: You might copy this as an answer.

Comment: @DidierPiau Done, I took me time, sine I tough was I told for the odd case was wrong, but now I am convinced it's not the case.

Comment: @Davide: I liked the short version better... *Ma non importa*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $a,b\in I$.
If $n$ is even, $n=2p$ just take $x_1=\ldots=x_p=a$ and $x_{p+1}=\ldots,=x_{2p}=b$.
We get 
$$f\left(\frac 1{2p}\left(\sum_{j=1}^pa+\sum_{j=1}^pb\right)\right)\leq \frac{\sum_{j=1}^pf(a)+\sum_{j=1}^pf(b)}{2p},$$
so 
$$f\left(\frac{pa+pb}{2p}\right)\leq \frac{pf(a)+pf(b)}{2p}\Rightarrow f\left(\frac{a+b}2\right)\leq \frac{f(a)+f(b)}2.$$

If $n=2p+1$, put $x_1=\ldots=x_p=a$, $x_{p+1}=\ldots=x_{2p}=b$ and $x_{2p+1}=\frac{a+b}2\in I$. We get, using 2. that 
$$f\left(\frac{a+b}2\right)=f\left(\frac{pa+\frac a2+pb+\frac b2}{2p+1}\right)\leq 
\frac{pf(a)+pf(b)+f\left(\frac{a+b}2\right)}{2p+1}$$ 
so $$f\left(\frac{a+b}2\right)\left(1-\frac 1{2p+1}\right)\leq p\frac{f(a)+f(b)}{2p+1}$$
hence $2pf\left(\frac{a+b}2\right)\leq p(f(a)+f(b))$, QED.