# Mid-Point Convexity Implies Convexity in Banach Spaces?

Tags: banach-spaces, convex-analysis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Showing that $f$ is convex](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83383/showing-that-f-is-convex)

Let $X$ be a real Banach space and $f:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a continuous function. We say that $f$ is Mid-Point convex if for all $x,y\in X$ $$\tag{1}f\Big(\frac{x+y}{2}\Big)\leq \frac{f(x)}{2}+\frac{f(y)}{2}$$

Can I conclude from (1) that $f$ is convex?

Comment: I know that if I can prove $$f(\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y)\leq\lambda f(x)+(1-\lambda)f(y)$$ for all $x,y\in X$ and $\lambda \in (0,1)$ rational, then by continuity the result follows.

Comment: Tomás: Thank you.  Perhaps it would be easier to work with the (still dense) set of rationals of the form $a/2^n$.

Comment: It is easy to show that it holds for all dyadic-rational $\lambda$.

Comment: @5PM is right, please disregard my qeustion.