# Convex continuous functions

Tags: analysis

\begin{equation}
w \left (\dfrac{x+y}{2} \right ) \le \dfrac{1}{2}(w(x) +w(y)) \quad \mbox{for all}  \quad  x,y \in \Omega,
\end{equation}
is a sufficient condition to a continuous function $w \in C^0(\Omega)$ be convex?

Comment: The one-dimensional case is proved [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/589546/if-f-is-continuous-why-is-f-with-the-property-f-left-fracxy2-right), the general follows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes---as long as $\Omega$, the domain of the function $w$, is a convex set.

This is called the "midpoint test" for convexity. I did a little Googling and found [this post](http://matthewhr.wordpress.com/2013/01/30/another-proof-that-midpoint-convex-and-continuous-implies-convex/) that offers a proof for the scalar case. And since a function is convex if and only if it is convex along every line, that should be sufficient.

EDIT: Actually, it looks like [this is a duplicate question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83383/showing-that-f-is-convex).