# Sufficient condition for convexity

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions, continuity, convex-analysis

Let f:$ [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ a continous function

such that  $ \forall (x,y) \in [a,b]^{2}, \exists t \in ]0,1[, f(tx+(1-t)y) \le tf(x) + (1-t)f(y) $

show that f is convex

Comment: In what way does this differ from the fundamental definition of convexity?

Comment: What definition on convexity are you using?

Comment: @Winther $\forall t \in [0,1]$ or $\forall t \in ]0,1[$ are the same because the cases t=0 or t=1 are obvious

Comment: @Winther, please read the question and compare it with the definition, this is not an easy question.

Comment: Sorry about that, I did not see the quantifier $\exists$. I thought it was $\forall$. Then I agree.

Comment: @Winther, it's allright :D

Comment: You can modify the proof [given here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1002248/if-f-is-continuous-and-f-big-frac12xy-big-le-frac12-big-fx?rq=1) for the case where the value of $t$ for a given $x,y$ is $t_* = \frac{1}{2}$. This changes a few details in that proof, but I think the rest should go through. The first inequality he has becomes $C_f(\alpha t_* + (1-t_*)\beta) \leq t_* C_f(\alpha) + (1-t_*)C_f(\beta)$. Secondly $\alpha,\beta\in S_\epsilon\to \frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}\in S_\epsilon$ becomes $\alpha t_* + (1-t_*)\beta\in S_\epsilon$. Then just a few more modifications to finish it.

Comment: sorry @Winther, t is not necessarily the same, for every couple $(x,y)$ there exist a real $t_{x,y}$ (t depends on x and y), the proof that you gave is not available in this case, but it works with this $\exists t \in (0,1), \forall (x,y) \in [a,b]^{2} .... $

Comment: Ah, I see, this is somewhat like the midpoint definition of convexity. Very cool!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is that a convex combination of convex combinations of two numbers $a$ and $b$ is itself a convex combination of $a$ and $b$,

Assume by contradiction that $f$ is not convex. There exist $x_0,x_1\in [a,b],\ t_0\in[0,1]$, ($x_0<x_1$ for simplicity) such that $f(x_{t_0})>(1-t_0)f(x_0)+t_0f(x_1)$, where $x_{t}:=(1-t) x_0+t x_1$, $0\le t\le 1$.

You prove that $0<t_0<1$.

Denote by $g(t):=f(x_{t})-(1-t)f(x_0)-tf(x_1)$. Since $g$ is continuous and positive at $t_0\in(0,1)$ it stays positive on a whole non-degenerate interval $[u,v]\subset(0,1)$.

Let $\alpha:=\inf \{t\in[0,\alpha]\mid g(s)>0.\forall\ s\in[t,v]\}$.

You prove that $g(\alpha)=0$. Also, you need to define similarly $\omega>\alpha$ such that $g(\omega)=0$ and $g$ stays positive on $(\alpha,\omega)$.

Now we use the given assumption for $x=x_\alpha$, $y=x_\omega$ to get a $t\in(0,1)$ such that $f(tx_\alpha+(1-t)x_\omega)\le tf(x_\alpha)+(1-t)f(x_\omega)$ together with the facts that $tx_\alpha+(1-t)x_\omega=x_s$ (for what $s$? -- very easy to guess), $s\in(\alpha,\omega)$, $f(x_\alpha)=(1-\alpha)f(x_0)+\alpha f(x_1)$, and similarly for $f(x_\omega)$. You get a contradiction from the previous inequality. You need to complete all details and/or simplify this proof.

Where is the condition $t\in(0,1)$ essential?

Comment: I think, it should be $ \alpha = inf \left\{ t \in [u,t_0] \ | \ g(t)>0 \right\} $ and $ \omega = sup \left\{ t \in [t_0, v] \ | \ g(t_0)>0 \right\} $, but your idea is good. Well done.

Answer (score 0):

A proof might go like this
(i.e., this is incomplete):

Suppose that $f$ is not convex.
Then there are two  points
$P=(u, f(u))$
and
$Q=(v, f(v))$
such that the line between them
is sometimes below
$f$;
i.e., there is a
$t \in (0, 1)$
such that,
if $w = tu+(1-t)v$,
then
$f(w) < tf(u)+(1-t)f(v)$.

Since $f$ is continuous,
there is a region around $w$
where the line connecting such points
is completely below $f$.
This is the part I'm not completely
sure of how to prove.
I think that we could
narrow regions where a point on the line
is below $f$
and use the continuity of $f$
to establish an interval
where the line is below the curve.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $f$ is not convex. It means there is an interval $[x,y]\subset[a,b]$ where the line between $x$ and $y$ is above the curve:
$$
\exists x,y\in[a,b],\forall t\in[0,1]:f(tx+(1-t)y) > tf(x) + (1-t)f(y)
$$
which is equivalent to
$$
\exists x,y\in[a,b],\not\exists t\in[0,1]:f(tx+(1-t)y) \le tf(x) + (1-t)f(y)
$$
This contradicts the hypothesis.

Answer (score 0):

By bissection, you can go to $\forall(x,y)\in[a,b]^2,\forall t\in]0,1[, f(tx+(1−t)y)≤tf(x)+(1−t)f(y)$

Let $(x,y) \in [a,b]^2$, let $t^* \in [0,1]$. We want to prove that $$f(t^*x+(1−t^*)y)≤t^*f(x)+(1−t^*)f(y)$$. By property, there exist $t_0$ such as

$$f(t_0x+(1−t_0)y)≤t_0f(x)+(1−t_0)f(y)$$

Let $x_0 =  t_0x + (1 -t_0)y$. If $t \in [x, x_0]$, there exist $t_1$ such as

\begin{eqnarray}
f(t_1x+(1−t_1)x_0)) & ≤ & t_1f(x)+(1−t_1)f(x_0) \\
 & \leq & t_1f(x)+(1−t_1)t_0f(x)+(1−t_0)f(y) \\
 & \leq & (t_1 + (1-t_1)t_0) f(x) + (1-t_1)(1-t_0)f(y)
\end{eqnarray}

and so forth, you have $t \in [t_{i} , t_{j}]$, with inequality verified by $x_i$ and $x_j$ and both converging to $t$. With continuity of $f$, it's done.

Comment: why did you write if $ t \in [x,x_0] $, t, x and $ x_0 $ are in general in different intervals $0 \le t \le 1 $, but, $ a \le x, x_0, y \le b $, for example if $a > 1$, please correct if I'm wrong.