# Do I have the correct visual intuition for convex & concave functions?

Tags: calculus, intuition

Consider a function $f$ defined over an interval $[a,b]$.

We say that $f$ is convex over $[a,b]$ if, for every pair of points $d,p$ in $[a,b]$ such that $d<p$, the slope of $f$ at $p$ is greater than or equal to the slope of $f$ at $d$.

So, as we sweep across $[a,b]$ from left to right, the slope of $f$ never decreases (and in the case of strict convexity, the slope is always increasing as we sweep across the interval).

And we say that $f$ is concave over $[a,b]$ if the opposite is true, i.e, if, as we sweep across $[a,b]$ from left to right, the slope of $f$ never increases (and in the case of strict concavity always decreases).

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: ConVex : the profile is like a V ($\cup$) ; ConcAve : the profile is like a A ($\cap$) ; your intuition is correct.

Comment: That is a good intuition of convexity, with the caveat that the slope may not always be defined. For example, $|x|$ is convex on $\mathbb R$ but its slope is undefined at $x=0$.

Comment: @dxiv I haven't studied continuity (or discontinuity) yet. Will I confuse myself if I try to think about special cases like that right now?

Comment: @MahdiRkioui Slope is about differentiability, not continuity. A convex function *must* be continuous, and $|x|$ *is* continuous at $0$, but it is not differentiable at $0$ and therefore the slope is undefined there. The intuition is fine, but you have to keep in mind it's just that, an intuition, not a substitute for the formal definition of convexity.

Comment: @dxiv Ok, I think I understand; the formal definition takes into account these special cases while this intuition doesn't. I assume this is why concavity and convexity isn't defined with derivatives. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are correct and your conclusions about the slope essentially give you an intuition for [relating this to second derivative](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1224955/proving-that-the-second-derivative-of-a-convex-function-is-nonnegative), as it is the derivative of a slope.