# prove that f is convex on (a,b) if and only if f satisfies $ f( \frac{x+y}{2} ) \leq \frac{f(x)+f(y)}{2} $ for all $ x,y \in (a,b) $

Tags: convex-analysis

Problem

> Let $f$ be continuous on (a,b). prove that $f$ is convex on (a,b) if and only if $f$ satisfies $ f( \frac{x+y}{2} ) \leq \frac{f(x)+f(y)}{2} $ for all  $x,y \in (a,b) $

I thought that it is easy by using the definition of convex

> a function f on (a,b) is said to be convex if 
>   $f(tx+(1-t)y)$ $ \leq $ $tf(x) + (1-t)f(y)$ for all $ x,y \in (a,b) $ and $ t \in [0,1] $

But my professor said that I was wrong. "you should use induction" 
I didn't understand what he said, but he doesn't say anymore.
How can I prove this?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1002248/if-f-is-continuous-and-f-big-frac12xy-big-le-frac12-big-fx and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83383/midpoint-convex-and-continuous-implies-convex?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: You're definitely not wrong, but (putting t=1/2) you have only shown the "only if" part of the statement. You need to check the "if" part.