# Equivalence of semi concavity of function $g$ and convexity of function $x\mapsto \frac c 2 |x|^2 - g(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

$g\in C^2(\mathbb R^n)$ is called semi concave, if there exists $c>0$ such that for all $x,y\in\mathbb R^n$ the following holds: $$g(x+y) - 2g(x) + g(x-y) \leq c|y|^2$$

Now, in Evans "Partial Differential Equations", it is said that "it is easy to check that" $g$ is semi concave iff the mapping $x\mapsto \frac c 2 |x|^2 - g(x)$ is convex.

I do not find it that easy to check. I tried showing that $x\mapsto \frac C 2 |x|^2 -g(x)$ is convex by straigtforward calculation and estimation, but this did not get me very far.

Using $(a+b)^2 \leq 2a^2+2b^2$ I got this far:

\begin{align*}
 &  \frac C 2 |\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y|^2 - g(\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y) \\
\leq & C\left(\lambda^2 |x|^2 + (1-\lambda)^2|y|^2\right) - g(\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y) 
\end{align*}

How  can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The starting point is the easily verified identity 
$$|x+y|^2 - 2|x|^2 + |x-y|^2 = 2|y|^2\tag1$$
Because of it, the inequality  $g(x+y) - 2g(x) + g(x-y) \leq c|y|^2$ is equivalent to 
$$g(x+y)-\frac c2|x+y|^2 - 2\left(g(x)-\frac c2|x|^2\right) + g(x-y)-\frac c2|x-y|^2 \le 0\tag2$$
Write $h(x)= \frac c 2 |x|^2 - g(x)$ for brevity; then (2) becomes
$$h(x+y)-2h(x)+h(x-y)\ge 0\tag3$$
Note that (3) is exactly the *midpoint convexity* of $h$. For continuous functions, it is equivalent to convexity: see [Midpoint-Convex and Continuous Implies Convex](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/83383/). Or you can let $y\to 0$, relate (3) to second order derivative, and observe that   the Hessian of $h$ is positive semidefinite.

Comment: Thank you very much! Wow, so the proof is indeed easy, at least if you know identity (1).