# On convexity of $\frac{1}{x}$

Tags: convex-analysis

I would like to prove  convexity of $\frac{1}{x}$. It can be proved by using second derivative but I want  without using second derivative. Can someone help me?

Comment: Have you tried to use Jensen's inequality?

Comment: Find relationship between $\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}$ and $\frac{2}{a+b}$

Comment: Thank you would you please more explain?

Comment: Use the definition of convexity.

Comment: It is easy to see that $\frac{a+b}{ab}<\frac{2}{ab}$ by assuming $a<1,b<1$ then?

Comment: Show that $\frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b}\right) \geq \frac{1}{\frac{a+b}{2}}$ for any $a>0, b>0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use [this criterion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83383/showing-that-f-is-convex-given-that-f-fracxy2-le-fracfxfy2). Now pick $x>0$, $y>0$ and remark that 
$$
f \left( \frac{x+y}{2} \right) \leq \frac{f(x)+f(y)}{2}
$$
is equivalent to
$$
\frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y} \right) \geq \frac{1}{\frac{x+y}{2}}.
$$
By some algebraic manipulation, this is in turn equivalent to $(x+y)^2 \geq 4xy$, or $x^2-2xy +y^2 \geq 0$. Of course this is always true, since $x^2-2xy+y^2= (x-y)^2$.