# Proving that $x \mapsto \frac1x$ is convex (without differentiating)

Tags: inequality, convex-analysis

I know that the function $x \mapsto \frac1x$ is convex when  $x \in (0,\infty)$. This can be proven easily by showing that the second derivative is positive. However, I am finding difficulty showing it using the definition of convexity, in other words, for $\alpha \in [0,1]$ and $x_1, x_2 \in \Bbb R^+$, show that:

$$\frac{1}{\alpha x_1 + (1-\alpha) x_2 } \leq \frac{\alpha}{x_1}+\frac{1-\alpha}{x_2}$$
Note that the relation between the harmonic mean and arithmetic mean is just a special case, (take $\alpha = 0.5$).

Comment: Compute the right-hand side minus the left-hand side. Then factor the fraction you get.

Comment: Since $1/x$ is continuous, inequality for $\alpha=0.5$ implies inequality for all $\alpha\in[0,1]$ (just think of binary search for $\alpha$).

Comment: Thanks for the comments,
@A.S. this is interesting, why this is true, can you put it in a more formal way.

Comment: $\alpha=1/2$ implies all $\alpha$ with finite binary expansion. Continuity extends it to all $\alpha$. Serpinski theorem says that Lebesgue integrability is sufficient for extension.

Comment: Related to the point made by @A.S. see also [Midpoint-Convex and Continuous Implies Convex](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83383/midpoint-convex-and-continuous-implies-convex).

Comment: I see, thanks @dxiv , I was not aware that mid point convexity implies convexity for continuous functions although it kind of intuitive.(the theorem by Jake).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We want to show that
$\frac{1}{a x + (1-a) y } 
\leq \frac{a}{x}+\frac{1-a}{y}
$

The right side is
$ \frac{a}{x}+\frac{1-a}{y}
=\frac{ay+(1-a)x}{xy}
=\frac{a(y-x)+x}{xy}
$
and the left side is
$\frac{1}{a x + (1-a) y }
=\frac{1}{a (x-y) + y }
$
so we want
$\frac{1}{a (x-y) + y} 
\le \frac{a(y-x)+x}{xy}
$.

Cross multiplying,
this is

$\begin{array}\\
xy
&\le (a (x-y) + y)(a(y-x)+x)\\
&=-a^2(x-y)^2+ay(y-x)+ax(x-y)+xy\\
&=-a^2(x-y)^2+a(x-y)(x-y)+xy\\
&=-a^2(x-y)^2+a(x-y)^2+xy\\
&=(a-a^2)(x-y)^2+xy\\
&=a(1-a)(x-y)^2+xy\\
\end{array}
$

And since both
$a(1-a) \ge 0$
and
$(x-y)^2 \ge 0$
the result follows.

Answer (score 8):

Let $x,y$ be positive  and $a+b=1$ with $a,b\in [0,1].$ We will use the fact that $$a^2+b^2=(a+b)^2-2 a b=1-2 a b.$$  Eliminating the denominators, we have $$ a/x+b/y\geq 1/(a x+b y)$$   $$\iff (a x+ b y)(a y+b x)\geq x y$$ $$\iff  (a^2+b^2)x y +a b(x^2+y^2)\geq x y $$ $$\iff (1-2 a b)x y +a b (x^2+y^2)\geq x y$$  $$ \iff -2 a bx y+a b(x^2+y^2)\geq 0$$ $$ \iff a b (x-y)^2\geq 0.$$

Comment: Yup. So many inequalities come down to $x^2 \ge 0$. And to think we did this over 5 years ago.