# Proof for convexity of a function

Tags: real-analysis, functions, convex-analysis, functional-inequalities

A continuous function is called *convex* on an interval $I\subseteq\mathbb R$ iff $$\forall x,y\in I\;\forall t\in[0,1]:f\big((1-t)x+ty\big)\leq (1-t)f(x)+tf(y).$$
I want to prove that this is equivalent to
$$\forall x,y\in I:f\left(\frac{x+y}2\right)\leq \frac{f(x)+f(y)}2.$$
One direction is clear as the second inequality follows from the first one if you choose $t=\frac12$.

However, I am getting stuck proving the reverse direction. How should I proceed here?

By the way, it seems like the second inequality is just a special case of the first one for $t=\frac12$ and is therefore weaker. How can both definitions be equivalent then?

Comment: The reverse implication only works for continuous functions, see for example [Midpoint-Convex and Continuous Implies Convex](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83383/midpoint-convex-and-continuous-implies-convex).

Comment: Do you know that $\mathbb{R}$ is  Cauchy complete?

Comment: It is not equivalent unless you add some other conditions. Continuity is a straightforward one.

Comment: A little work shows that if the second holds the the first formula is true whenever $t$ is of the form ${k \over 2^n}$ for $k \in \{0,...,2^n\}$. Then you can use continuity to extend to all of $[0,1]$.

Comment: @dxiv, copper.hat: You are right, the function should be continuous. I added that in my question.

Comment: @Mophotla The question is fully answered in the post I linked to in my first comment.