# Given $f(\frac{x_1 + x_2}{2})$ $\le\frac{(f(x_1) + f(x_2))}{2}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $f$ be bounded in $[a,b]$. Assume $f$ satisfies 
$$f\left(\frac{x_1 + x_2}{2}\right) \le\frac{f(x_1) + f(x_2)}{2}$$
for all $a\le x_1 \le x_2 \le b $ . Prove that $f$ is continous on $x$ when $a< x < b$.

I'm more concerned with how I can derive the prove of this question

Comment: I'm curious about why people put close votes on a problem like this.

Answer (score 1):

A function that satisfies
$$f\left(\frac{x_1 + x_2}{2}\right) \le\frac{f(x_1) + f(x_2)}{2}$$
is called *midpoint convex*, which is a slightly weaker notion than convexity.

While every convex function is midpoint convex, not every midpoint convex function is convex. Every convex function is contiuous. Also, every continuous, midpoint convex function is convex. However, not every midpoint convex function is contiunous. A counterexample is contructed [here](http://www.mathcounterexamples.net/a-discontinuous-midpoint-convex-function/).

EDIT: I overlooked that the counterexample in the link is not bounded. So the problem is still open.

EDIT 2: According to [this paper](https://cms.math.ca/10.4153/CJM-1950-046-x) by Green and Gustin, Ostrowski showed in [a paper](https://www.digizeitschriften.de/dms/img/?PID=GDZPPN002128675) in 1929, written in german, that every midpoint convex function, bounded above on a set of positive measure is continuous. On his part, Ostrowski refers to [a paper](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.acta/1485887155) by Jensen from 1906, written in French, where it is shown on p. 188 that every bounded midpoint convex function is continuous. Thus we are done.

Comment: The counterexample is not bounded..

Comment: A fair point. I overlooked that part in the question.

Answer (score 0):

$f(x)$ is bounded on $[a,b]$ and it is convex function on$[a,b]$ so it is continuous on $(a,b)$

Comment: Why is it convex?

Comment: @xyz The question only presumes that $f$ is *midpoint* convex, which doesn't directly imply convexity *unless* you make additional assumptions such as continuity (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function#Properties) or [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83383/midpoint-convex-and-continuous-implies-convex) for example), so your proposed answer is circular.