# prove that the following function is convex at least I want a hint

Tags: measure-theory, functions, proof-verification, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Let we have the following function 
$$ψ:R^{*+} \to R$$
        $$x\to ψ(x)=x^3$$
 How can I prove that $ψ$ is a convex function by using the definition ?

I meant that  I have to prove that 
$$ψ(λx+(1-λ)y) \le λψ(x)+ (1-λ)ψ(y)$$ where $λ \in [0,1] $ $x$ and $y$ belong to $R^{*+}$

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math.Se. Please take the tour (http://math.stackexchange.com/tour) and look at a few other (upvoted) questions to learn more about how to ask questions here. In particular, it would be good if you can include your efforts on the problem, and if you read the tag descriptions before using them (for example proof-verification doesn't fit).

Comment: calculate $\psi''$ ?

Comment: @zwim by using the definition

Comment: $R^{*+}$ is what?

Comment: @PaulSinclair the set of all real positive numbers without zero

Answer (score 1):

Take $a,b$ positive reals. Then for $a \ge b$, we have $a^2+ab \ge 2b^2$, that is, $a^2 + ab+b^2 \ge 3b^2$. Multiplying by $(a-b)$, we get $a^3 - b^3 \ge 3b^2(a-b)$.

For $a\le b$, we have $a^2+ab \le 2b^2$, that is, $a^2+ab+b^2 \le 3b^2$. Here $(a-b) \le 0$, so multiplying by $(a-b)$, we have $a^3-b^3 \ge 3b^2(a-b)$.

Thus for any positive reals $a,b$, we have $a^3-b^3 \ge 3b^2(a-b)$, that is, $a^3 \ge b^3 + 3b^2(a-b). \tag{1}$

Taking $a = x, b = \lambda x + (1- \lambda)y$ in the above inequality, we get
$$ x^3 \ge (\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y)^3 + 3b^2(1-\lambda)(x-y) \tag{2}$$

Taking $a = y, b = \lambda x + (1- \lambda)y$ in $(1)$, we get 
$$ y^3 \ge (\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y)^3 + 3b^2(-\lambda)(x-y) \tag{3}$$

Now, $\lambda \times (2) + (1-\lambda) \times (3)$ gives
$$\lambda x^3 + (1-\lambda)y^3 \ge (\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y)^3 $$

That proves convexity the way you want.

Note though that everything we did above follows from Taylor's theorem and non-negativity of the second derivative and is in fact a proof in disguise of the fact that a non-negative second derivative implies convexity. You are better off just using that.

Comment: Are you sure about (2) and (3) inequalities  ?

Comment: Why, where do you think there's a problem?

Comment: Sorry there is no problem

Answer (score 0):

Note that,
if $f(x) = x^3$,
then
$f''(x)
=6x
$.

Therefore
$f(x)$ is
concave (down)
for $x < 0$
and
convex (up)
for $x > 0$.

At $x = 0$ it is neither.

Applying the linear definition
is harder.

Comment: By using the definition

Comment: I meant that  I have to prove that 
$$ψ(λx+(1-λ)y) \le λψ(x)+ (1-λ)ψ(y)$$ where $λ \in [0,1] $ $x$ and $y$ belong to $R^{*+}$

Comment: Please help me i need to prove it by using the definition

Comment: Then expand the cube and see what cancels. Hint: write it as $f(ax+(1-a)y)  \le af(x)+(1-a)f(y)$ to save typing.

Comment: What do you mean exactly

Comment: Can you help me more please sir

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  since $\psi$ is continuous, it is sufficient to prove that it is [midpoint convex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function#Properties) since [Midpoint-Convex and Continuous Implies Convex](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83383/midpoint-convex-and-continuous-implies-convex).

Midpoint convexity on $\mathbb{R}^{+}$ amounts to proving that for $\forall a,b \ge 0\,$:

$$
\begin{align}
\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)^3 \le \frac{a^3+b^3}{2} \quad & \iff \quad a^3+3a^2b+3ab^2+b^3 \le 4a^3+4b^3 \\
& \iff \quad 0 \le 3(a^3-a^2b-ab^2+b^3) \\
& \iff \quad 0 \le 3(a+b)(a-b)^2
\end{align}
$$