# $f(x)=x^3$ is convex nor concave without to derivate

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, discrete-mathematics, real-numbers

Drawing the graph of a function is not intuitive. For example, the function $f(x)=x^2$ is special, we can say that given two points of the function the straight line that join those points is above the function. So we write 
$$
x_2<(x_1+x_0)(x-x_0)+x^2 
$$
How did I obtain the part of the right? 
$$
(Y-x_0^2)/   (x-x_0)  =     (x_1^2 -  x_0^2)   /      (x_1 -   x_0)
$$
Now I just isolate Y in the equation above.

My question is, can I do the same with $f(x)=x^3$? 
And how do I prove it? Can I say that $x^3$ is below the straight line that join two points of the function $x^3$? If and only if $x$ is positive.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you are asking, but...if you draw the line from $(-1,(-1)^3)$ to $(1,1^3)$, can you show that there are portions of the curve that lie both above and below that line?

Comment: Sorry. My english sometimes only sucks. I can prove that by deriving the function... but what I want is doing the same without it.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:   for $\,x_{0,1} \ge 0\,$ the [generalized means inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_mean#Definition) gives $\,\sqrt[3]{\dfrac{x_0^3+x_1^3}{2}} \ge \dfrac{x_0+x_1}{2}\,$, which is equivalent to $\,f(x)=x^3\,$ being midpoint-convex on $\,\Bbb R^+\,$. By continuity, [it follows that](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83383/midpoint-convex-and-continuous-implies-convex) $\,f(x)\,$ is in fact convex on $\,\Bbb R^+\,$. More generally, the same argument works for $\,f(x)=x^n\,$, $\,n \ge 1\,$.

---

[ *EDIT* ]   Since $\,f(x)=x^3\,$ is an odd function, it follows that it is concave on $\,\Bbb R^-\,$. Since the direction of concavity changes at $0$, the function is neither convex nor concave on the entire $\,\Bbb R^\,$.

Comment: Thanks!! Your are right. :) that's a new point of view.

Comment: But can I do the same only with the definition of the straight rect and de function of x^3?

Comment: @Josselyn `do the same` Do you mean determine convexity on the half-axes, or prove it is not convex on the entire axis, or something else? `only with` Not sure what you mean to *exclude* from being used in a proof by that `only`.

Answer (score 1):

For a graph of a function to be convex the [epigraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epigraph_(mathematics)) must be a convex set. This means I can take any two points in the set and draw a straight line between them without leaving the set. To see that this isn't true for $f(x)=x^3$ take any $x < 0$ and draw the line from $(x,f(x))$ to the point $(0,0)$ which are both in the epigraph of the function, but none of the points between them are in the epigraph so $f(x)$ cannot be convex. The concave case is the same but with $x>0$.

Comment: That's right. So I can take two different cases. Whenever I take x<0 or x>0. So, now I have to prove that x3>(x1+x0)(x-x0)+x^2 if x is negative and the other case when x is positive.

Comment: And I don't know where do I start. Because my domain is x€[x0,x1]

Comment: @Josselyn you only need two points as counter-examples and if you consider $x=\pm 1$ then consider the linear segment connecting it to with $(0,0)$. This is simply $y=x$ on both sides of the origin. What can you tell me about $y=(-\frac{1}{2})^3$ versus $y=-\frac{1}{2}$?