# How do I prove this inequality of a convex function on an interval

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions, convex-analysis, alternative-proof

Suppose h is a continuous function on the interval $[0:1]$ such that for any $t_1, t_2 \in
[0,1]$
$$ h\left(\frac{t_1 + t_2}{2}\right) \leq \frac{h(t_1) + h(t_2)}{2}$$

Show that for all natural number $n \geq 2$, and any points $t_1,t_2, \dots, t_n$ 
$$ h\left(\frac{t_1+t_2+\cdots + t_n}{n}\right)\leq \frac{h(t_1)+h(t_2)+\dots+h(t_n)}{n} 
$$

I have already attempted this problem, My approach was to use the first condition and that h is continuous to prove h is convex on the  interval, and using the convexity of h to show using induction on n that the inequality holds. Now I was wondering, is there an alternative way to prove this such that I do not need to prove that h is convex?

Comment: When $n=2^{m}$ we can prove this by  a  simple induction argument.

Comment: Hmm but what about for n != 2**m, seems like establishing the convexity of h seems like the only approach to this problem though...

Comment: Use backward induction

Comment: Oh I get it, we reasn backwards from 2**m, thanks alot. So continuity is not really needed here

Comment: You indeed don't need continuity for the "average-point-convexity" property you set out to prove. However, if you do not assume continuity, you cannot prove that the function is convex, unless it is also measurable - and then the proof is non-trivial. To see how full convexity is proved from your assumption, including continuity, see here:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3211912/how-do-i-prove-this-inequality-of-a-convex-function-on-an-interval

Comment: @uniquesolution Please give the correct link! Your link leads me to the current question.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83383/midpoint-convex-and-continuous-implies-convex