# Show convexity of a continued fraction

Tags: convex-analysis, continued-fractions

Prove convexity of function

$$f(x_1, x_2 \dots x_n):=\dfrac{1}{x_1 - \dfrac{1}{x_2 - \dfrac{1}{\ddots - \dfrac{1}{x_n}}}}$$

defined on subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, where every denominator is strictly positive.

I was thinking about induction (and I would like not to try to differentiate that). Also I was trying to use proven fact from this link:

[Midpoint-Convex and Continuous Implies Convex](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83383/midpoint-convex-and-continuous-implies-convex)

But it works only when $f$ is continuous, which we seem not to have here.

Comment: Why is $f$ not continuous, under the restriction that every denominator is strictly positive (not just every $x_j$)?

Comment: Oh, shame on me... Tomorrow I'll try to prove that using continuity, thx!