# Proving that $f\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right) \le \frac{f(x)+f(y)}{2}$ is convex

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, solution-verification

I'm trying to prove:

> $f$ is a continuous real function defined in $(a, b)$ such that $$f\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right) \le \frac{f(x)+f(y)}{2}$$ for all $x, y \in (a, b) \implies f$ is convex.

I was also given:

> A real function $f$ defined in $(a, b)$ is said to be convex if $$f(\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y) \le \lambda f(x)+(1-\lambda)f(y)$$ whenever $a < x, y < b, 0<\lambda < 1$.

My attempt at *a* proof:  Let $x, y \in (a, b)$ and take $f$ be a continuous real function defined in $(a, b)$ such that $$f\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right) \le \frac{f(x)+f(y)}{2}.$$ Now, suppose to the contrary that $\exists x, y \in (a, b), \lambda \in (0, 1)$ such that $$f(\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y) > \lambda f(x)+(1-\lambda)f(y).$$ We claim that the equation above os satisfied if we take $\lambda = 0.5$, that is, we obtain $$f\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right) > \frac{f(x)+f(y)}{2}$$ which contradicts the definition of $f$.

Can someone please proofread this proof and let me know if it is accurate? If not, please just point out the error(s); please don't bother to suggest a new proof of this problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Midpoint-Convex and Continuous Implies Convex](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83383/midpoint-convex-and-continuous-implies-convex)

Comment: @Integrand Judging by the last sentence, I would say it does not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a rather serious error: you are concluding from your assumption of non-convexity that there is some $\lambda \in [0, 1]$ and $x, y$ such that
$$f(\lambda x + (1 - \lambda)y) > \lambda f(x) + (1 - \lambda)f(y).$$
This is fine, but then next you assume that this $\lambda = 1/2$. This assumption is erroneous. You can only assume $\lambda \in [0, 1]$, not any specific value of $\lambda$ you wish.

You will absolutely need the continuity assumption too; there are discontinuous counterexamples!

Comment: This is exactly what I had suspected, but I just wanted to be sure, thanks!