# Condition of concavity for a function

Tags: convex-analysis, convexity-inequality

I have a continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $\forall x,y\in\mathbb{R}^n$ I have that $f(x)\ge\cfrac{1}{2}f(x-y)+\cfrac{1}{2}f(x+y)$.

How can I prove that $\forall x,y\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\forall t\in[0,1]$ I have that $f(tx+(1-t)y)\ge tf(x)+(1-t)f(y)$ ?

Comment: Convexity would be $f(tx+(1-t)y)\leq tf(x)+(1-t)f(y)$. By the way:What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, $f(x)\ge\frac{1}{2}f(x-y)+\frac{1}{2}f(x+y)$ is no different from $f(\frac{x+y}{2})\ge\frac{1}{2}f(x)+\frac{1}{2}f(y)$.

Secondly, [Midpoint-Convex and Continuous Implies Convex](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83383/midpoint-convex-and-continuous-implies-convex)

Thirdly, A Lebesgue measurable function on an interval C is concave if and only if it is midpoint concave: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concave_function

Comment: Sure, my function is midpoint-convex, but what is the most easy way to show that midpoint-convex and continuous implies convex?