# Example of function satisfying for fixed $t\in (0,1)$ inequality $f(tx+(1-t)y) \leq tf(x)+(1-t)f(y)$

Tags: inequality, convex-analysis

I would like to know an example of function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ which is not convex but satisfies for fixed $t\in (0,1)$ the following inequality:
$$f(tx+(1-t)y) \leq t f(x)+(1-t)f(y) \textrm{  for all  } x,y \in \mathbb{R}.$$

I know only that such functions have to be discontinuous everywhere.

Comment: @JavaMan: Possibly Alex means that there is at least one $t\in(0,1)$ such that $f$ satisfies the inequality.

Comment: A function is convex iff satisfies this inequality for all $t\in(0,1)$ and all $x,y$. But in my question $t$ is fixed for. For example $t$ may be $t=\frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: Answers to this question suggest that for $t=1/2$ (i.e. for midpoint convex or Jensen convex functions) some form of AC is needed: [A counterexample for Big Rudin's Chapter 3 Exercise 4](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/71019/a-counterexample-for-big-rudins-chapter-3-exercise-4/)

Comment: Thanks. But I know that additive discontinuous function satisfies this inequality with $t=\frac{1}{2}$. I look for example for another $t$.

Comment: Examples based on a Hamel basis of $\mathbb R$ over $\mathbb Q$ will satisfy your inequality for all rational $t$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zoltán Daróczy, Zsolt Páles: *Convexity with given infinite weight sequences.*
Stochastica: revista de matemática pura y aplicada, ISSN 0210-7821, Vol. 11, No. 1, 1987, 5-12, [link to pdf](http://dmle.cindoc.csic.es/pdf/STOCHASTICA_1987_11_01_01.pdf).

> *Lemma 1.* Let $D\subseteq\mathbb R^n$ be a convex compact set. Let $f:D\to\mathbb R$ be an $\alpha$-convex function for some fixed $\alpha\in(0,1)$, i.e. assume that
>   $$f(\alpha x+(1-\alpha)y)\le \alpha f(x)+(1-\alpha)f(y) \qquad (\ast)$$
>   holds for all $x,y\in D$. Then $f$ is also Jensen convex, i.e. $(\ast)$ is satisfied with $\alpha=\frac12$.

According to the autors, the same result was obtained earlier by N. Kuhn in the paper *A note on t-convex functions,* but I was not able to find this paper online.

---

Based on the above result, it suffices to consider $t=\frac12$. It was explained in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/71019/a-counterexample-for-big-rudins-chapter-3-exercise-4/71055#71055) that some form of AC is needed to construct non-convex Jensen convex function. (Since every measurable Jensen convex function is convex.)

Comment: Thanks. It is very helpful.