# Mid-point convexity does not imply convexity

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, examples-counterexamples

A function $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is said to be mid-point convex if for all $x, y \in X$, we have 
$$f(\frac{x + y}{2}) \leq \frac{f(x) + f(y)}{2}. $$
Can you please give an example of a function which is mid-point convex but not convex?

Comment: Such a function would have to be non-measurable and so might be a little difficult to just "write down".

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan why non measurable ?

Comment: It is a theorem of someone (who I don't remember - but I suspect it is rather deep) that a measurable mid-point convex function is forced to be continuous - and hence convex (A midpoint convex function is always rationally convex)

Comment: I am really thankful to you all for the responses.

Comment: This seems to be the same question as [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/71019/a-counterexample-for-big-rudins-chapter-3-exercise-4). I will also add link to [this related post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83383/showing-that-f-is-convex-given-that-f-fracxy2-le-fracfxfy2). Other [questions linked there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/83383) might be of interest, too.

Answer (score -3):

That is a theorem on convex analysis but it is stated for continuous function.
For making counterexample you can remove the continuity from the condition such as
$f(x)=x^2$ for $x\in \mathbb{Q}$ and $0$ otherwise. I think that, it  is a counter example.

Comment: In fact, it is known that any counterexample cannot be measurable and that existence of such function cannot be shown in ZF. (See the linked questions.) Your example does not work. Just consider $x=2+\sqrt2$ and $y=-\sqrt2$. (Or any other two irrational numbers such that their average is a non-zero rational number.)

Comment: If a Midpoint Convex function F, strictly monotonic, increasing on a real interval $[0,1]\to[0,1]$, with $F(0)=0$ and $F(1)=1$ , $F(0.5)=0.5$ will it be measurable and convex, aside from the possible counter-examples. Generally strict quasi-convexity is sufficient under mild constraints