# mid-point convex but not a.e. equal to a convex function

Tags: functions, convex-analysis, examples-counterexamples

I recently stumbled upon Wikipedia's page on convexity (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function#Properties) and there's reference to Sierpinski's theorem from which we can deduce that for Lebesgue measurable functions mid-point convexity implies convexity. For reference: mid-point convexity means
$$f\left(\frac{1}{2} x + \frac{1}{2} y\right) \leq \frac{f(x) + f(y)}{2} \ldotp$$

Now, the question is: how pathological has to be an example of a mid-convex function that is not convex? The usual examples usually do something like 'put one value on rationals, different on non-rationals' but that won't work here, since such a function is a.e. equal to a convex, constant function.

I understand that since the function can't be measurable it has to be pretty weird, but how weird exactly in this case?

The only related question I've found is this one: [Mid-point convexity does not imply convexity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/762972/mid-point-convexity-does-not-imply-convexity) but it doesn't contain any examples, there's just a remark mentioning Sierpinski's result in the comments.

Comment: You'd need a function that is not Lebesgue measurable, which I think requires the axiom of choice.  So any "examples" would be non-constructive.

Comment: See also [this related question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/71019/a-counterexample-for-big-rudins-chapter-3-exercise-4). Maybe some references given in the answers to [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83383/showing-that-f-is-convex-given-that-f-fracxy2-le-fracfxfy2) and [other questions linked there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/83383) might be of interest.

Comment: I was about to give an example but the post has been deleted.