# How to find an everywhere discontinuous real function with $F((a+b)/2)<(F(a)+F(b))/2$?

Tags: analysis, convex-analysis

In **[here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/876410/an-explicit-construction-for-an-everywhere-discontinuous-real-function-with-f)** I posted a non-constructive everywhere discontinuous real function with
$$F((a+b)/2)=(F(a)+F(b))/2$$
based on the using of Hamel basis. And Conifold answered there that there is no explicit way to construct an every where discontinuous function with $F((a+b)/2)\leq(F(a)+F(b))/2$.

So here another question is, how to give a non-constructive everywhere discontinuous real function with a strict inequality
$$F((a+b)/2)<(F(a)+F(b))/2?$$

---

By non-constructive I mean the using of axiom of choice, but maybe someone more familiar with set theory have different ideas and welcome edits.

Comment: This isn't really a question about the axiom of choice. This is a question about finding a function which satisfies this inequality. The [axiom-of-choice] tag is unnecessary here.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I initially added it because I think it can be regarded as an application of the axiom of choice...

Comment: Yeah, that is probably an application of the axiom of choice. As are 60% of modern functional analysis, parts of ring theory, group theory, and in fact even freshman year calculus.

Comment: Again, the axiom of choice tag is not for "Well, this probably needs the axiom of choice". It's for asking specific questions *about* the axiom of choice. You already asked that part, you were told that the axiom of choice is needed to some degree in constructing a solution. Now you just seem to ask "Well, how can I construct this sort of solution?" and that's not quite what fits to the axiom of choice tag.

Comment: Note that your strict inequality is for $a\not =b$. With this restriction, the function $f(x)=x^2$ is such that your strict inequality is satisfied. Now if you take $G(x)$ an everywhere discontinuous function such that $G(\frac{a+b}{2})=\frac{G(a)+G(b)}{2}$ for all $a,b$, I think that $F(x)=G(x)+x^2$ is a solution.

Comment: @Kelenner This is a nice solution! If you post it as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/71019/example-of-a-function-such-that-varphi-left-fracxy2-right-leq-frac-va

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that your strict inequality is for $a\not =b$. With this restriction, the function $f(x)=x^2$ is such that your strict inequality is satisfied. Now if you take $G(x)$ an everywhere discontinuous function such that $G(\frac{a+b}{2})=\frac{G(a)+G(b)}{2}$ for all $a,b$, I think that $F(x)=G(x)+x^2$ is a solution.