# Show that $f$ is convex iff $f\left (\frac{1}{2}x + \frac{1}{2}y \right ) \leq \frac{1}{2} f(x) + \frac{1}{2} f(y)$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, convex-analysis, examples-counterexamples

Let $\Omega \subset \Bbb R^n$ be a convex set and $f: \Omega \to \Bbb R$ be continuous. Show that $f$ is convex if and only if for all $x,y \in \Omega$,
$$f\left (\frac{1}{2}x + \frac{1}{2}y \right ) \leq \frac{1}{2} f(x) + \frac{1}{2} f(y)$$
Give a counterexample to the same statement without the assumption that $f$ is continuous.

$\Rightarrow$ is obvious but I am not getting any clue for the other side. I was trying to proceed using the bisection method e.g. for $f(\lambda x+(1-\lambda )y)$ I was trying to approach $\lambda f( x)$ by halving the numbers say $\frac{\lambda x+(1-\lambda )y}{2}$ and same with $(1-\lambda)f( y)$ but it seemed to be not working. Please help me with the proof and the counterexample.

Comment: For the claim about continuous functions, see this question: [Midpoint-Convex and Continuous Implies Convex](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/83383) (and [other questions linked there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/83383)). For the counterexample, see this question: [Example of a function such that $\varphi\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)\leq \frac{\varphi(x)+\varphi(y)}{2}$ but $\varphi$ is not convex](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/71019) (and [other questions linked there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/71019)).

Comment: @MartinSleziak that should be an answer in my opinion.

Comment: @supinf I am not really sure about that. I was considering voting to close as a duplicate, however, there is a problem that there are actually two duplicate target. (Moreover, another difference is that this is about convex subset of $\mathbb R^n$ and the linked questions are about real functions - but I do not think that the change between $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb R^n$ changes the proof too much.)