# Inequality for convex function / Jensen's inequality

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-functions

We know that for a concave function $f\left(\frac{x_1+x_2}{2}\right) \geq \frac{f(x_1)+f(x_2)}2$.

Is it true that
$ f\left(\frac{\sum x_i}n\right) \geq \frac{\sum f(x_i)}n$ for finite $x_1, ... x_n$? I tried to prove it by myself using mathematical inductions, I have not sucessfully proved it yet. If it is possible, I would like prove only using $f\left(\frac{x_1+x_2}{2}\right) \geq \frac{f(x_1)+f(x_2)}2$ without other concave function properties.

I do not know if I miss something important. I thought it'd be a lot easier... Thanks in advance.

Comment: [This](https://youtu.be/dy-hpis58nc) video might help you

Comment: Yes, what you write is true for **concave** functions, not convex functions. Be aware that the inequality $f(\frac{x_1 + x_2}{2}) \ge \frac{f(x_1) + f(x_2)}{2}$ is the definition for midpoint-concavity, and is weaker than concavity in general (though not if the function is continuous).

Comment: Fixed, thank you :) It "Is weaker than concavity", but concavity implies midpoint-concavity(correct me if wrong). In that case, does midpoint-concavity implies the inequality in the post?

Comment: @Lab No it doesn't. It will if $n$ is a power of $2$, but not otherwise.

Comment: Can you give me a counterexample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $f : D \to \Bbb{R}$, where $D$ is a convex subset of some vector space (could just be $\Bbb{R}$ if you prefer). We say $f$ is **concave** if the inequality
$$f(\lambda x + (1 - \lambda)y) \ge \lambda f(x) + (1 - \lambda)f(y) \tag{$\star$}$$
holds whenever $x, y \in D$, and $\lambda \in [0, 1]$. If $(\star)$ holds just for $\lambda = 1/2$, we say $f$ is **midpoint-concave**. Note that trivially, concavity implies midpoint-concavity.

Concavity implies the inequality you wrote. We can prove it for all $n$ by induction. For $n = 1$, the inequality becomes an equality, and is trivially true. If it holds for some $n \ge 1$, then
\begin{align*}
f\left(\frac{x_1 + \ldots + x_n + x_{n+1}}{n + 1}\right) &= f\left(\frac{x_1 + \ldots + x_n}{n + 1} + \frac{x_{n+1}}{n + 1}\right) \\
&= f\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\frac{x_1 + \ldots + x_n}{n} + \frac{1}{n + 1}x_{n+1}\right) \\
&\ge \frac{n}{n+1}f\left(\frac{x_1 + \ldots + x_n}{n}\right) + \frac{1}{n + 1}f(x_{n+1}) \\
&\ge \frac{n}{n+1} \cdot \frac{f(x_1) + \ldots + f(x_n)}{n} + \frac{1}{n + 1}f(x_{n+1}) \\
&= \frac{f(x_1) + \ldots + f(x_n)}{n+1} + \frac{1}{n + 1}f(x_{n+1}) \\
&= \frac{f(x_1) + \ldots + f(x_n) + f(x_{n+1})}{n+1}.
\end{align*}

---

We now look at midpoint-concavity. Let
$$I = \{x \in \Bbb{Q} \cap [0, 1] : \exists p, q \in \Bbb{Z}, \text{ such that }x = p/2^q\}.$$
Note that, if $x, y \in I$, then $\frac{x + y}{2} \in I$ as well.

Midpoint-concavity implies that $(\star)$ holds for $\lambda \in I$. This set is dense in $[0, 1]$, so if $f$ is continuous, then midpoint-concavity implies concavity, and hence the average calculation above holds true. If $f$ is discontinuous, then we can find counterexamples. Check out [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/71019/example-of-a-function-such-that-varphi-left-fracxy2-right-leq-frac-va) for an example (though note that this is for convexity, not concavity; just take the negative).